# Github Actionsのワークフロー構文がSyntax Errorになる

Tags: github, github-actions, yaml

59行目にエラーがあると吐き出されます。
一階構文を確認したのですが、yamlは初めてなので、初心的な間違いをしてるかもしれません。
親切に教えてくださると幸甚です。

```yaml
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: Replace Tag & Push

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  replace:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Status
        run: |
          ls -XlR
          find -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 sha1sum > hash.txt
      - name: Delete all mdx files
        run: |
          rm -fv ./pages/*.mdx
      - name: Replace slug
        run: |
          mkdir arrange
          cp -fvr ./documents/* ./arrange/
      - name: Copy all mdx files
        run: |
          cp -fpvr ./arrange/* ./pages/
      - name: Delete
        run: rm -rf ./arrange
      - name: Hash Check
        run: |
          CURRENT_CACHE=`cat ./hash.txt`
          rm -f ./hash.txt
          NOW_CACHE=`find -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 sha1sum`
          if [ CURRENT_CACHE != NOW_CACHE ]; then
            echo "::set-output name=skip_ci::false"
          else
            echo "::set-output name=skip_ci::true"
          fi

  pushjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: replace
    if: ${{ needs.replace.outputs.skip_ci != 'true' }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Replace
        - run: |
          git config --global user.name "github-actions[bot]"
          git config --global user.email "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
          git pull
          git add -A
          git commit -m "Push replaced pages"
          git push
```

GitHubのメッセージ

```
Invalid workflow file
You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 59
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エラーメッセージの言っている行数とはずれていますが、ここは↓

```yaml
      - name: Replace
        - run: |
          git config --global user.name "github-actions[bot]"
```

`name` と `run` が同じ階層に居るべきなので、こうです。

```yaml
      - name: Replace
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "github-actions[bot]"
```

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun